# How to return a dynamic cell reference in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to return a formula reference to a cell in another sheet.

The code returns:

```
=@'Jobs and pricing info'!'E9'
```

and

```
=@'Jobs and pricing info'!'E10
```

and so on.

Why is there an @ at the beginning and why are there single quotes around the E9?

```vb
Sub LinkCells()

    Sheets("Direct Labor").Select
    Range("E122").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Jobs and pricing info'!E9"
    ActiveCell.Offset(145).Select
    
    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 1 To 199
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Jobs and pricing info'!E" & (9 + x)
        ActiveCell.Offset(145).Select
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Trying using `FormulaLocal`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formulalocal  `FormulaR1C1` uses (as the name suggests) a different syntax for cell references, using row and column numbers. eg Local=`E1`, R1C1=`R1C5`. The 'Local' is dependent upon regional settings as the letters used may be different depending on language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason it is adding the `@` is because you are trying to add a normal formula as a R1C1 formula. Rather than `.FormulaR1C1`, try just `.formula`.

Aside from that, there are various issues with your function, that whilst may not stop it working, it's not good practice.

For example, you should always fully qualify your references. If you say `Range("E122").Select`, I believe that defaults to the `ActiveWorkbook`. What happens if you have a different workbook active when the macro runs? That may be unlikely, but it can cause some very weird and hard to find bugs. It would be better to fully qualify it with: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Direct Labor").Range("E122").Select`.

This also has the benefit of combining two of your select statements into one.

Now... select statements... try to avoid them. They are slow and are usually easily replaceable. They can also cause bugs. For example, what happens if you select a different cell when the macro is half way through running?

Instead, you can refer to ranges/cells directly:

```
Sub LinkCells()

    Dim CurrentCell as Range
    Set CurrentCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Direct Labor").Range("E122")

    CurrentCell.Formula="='Jobs and pricing info'!E9"

    Set CurrentCell = CurrentCell.Offset(145)

    Dim x As Long
    For x = 1 To 199
        CurrentCell.formula = "='Jobs and pricing info'!E" & (9 + x)
        Set CurrentCell=CurrentCell.Offset(145)
    Next x
End Sub
```

P.S. Note that I also changed your `Dim x As Integer` to `Dim x As Long`.
This is because on modern (32 bit) systems, VBA Integers are converted to Long for processing anyway. You are not saving any memory by using Integer instead of Long. However, by using Integer you will still cause an overflow if you enter a value greater than 32767 (or less than -32768). So, basically, you may as well always use Long except for extremely specific circumstances (e.g. interfacing with a legacy 16bit API).

Comment: Thank you so much! It does work like this, but I figured it wasn't perfect. I'll check out your suggestions and read up about it some more.